# Type String has no member document type

Tags: html, swift, string

I want to create an string extension to create a string from a html code.

Therefore I use this code:

```
NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Sadly there appears the error message "Type 'String' has no member 'documentType'".

Comment: What is your Xcode/Swift version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1:**

```
extension String {
    func htmlStr(data: Data) {
        do {
            let outputStr = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
            print(outputStr)
        } catch (let err) {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful if they explain the problem and the solution, instead of dumping code only.